# Can I do multi mapping with redbeanphp?

Tags: redbean

can I load an object and it's relations with just a query?

so, if I have

```
select * from parent inner join child on parent.id = child.parent_id
```

could I get and array of parent beans with is ownChild informed just from that query?

something like multi mapping in dapper:
https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. This is documented as "[Find Multiple](http://www.redbeanphp.com/finding#find_multi)" in the RedBean manual.

Example with you query:

```
<?php

require 'rb.php'; // 4.2.4, for the record

R::setup();

// --- Fixtures ---

$parent = R::dispense('parent');
$parent->name = "Foo";

$child = R::dispense('child');
$child->name = "Bar";
$childId = R::store($child);

$parent->ownChildList[] = $child;
$parentId = R::store($parent);

// --- Multi Mapping ---

$beans = R::findMulti( 'parent,child', '
    SELECT parent.*, child.* FROM parent
    INNER JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
    WHERE parent.id = ?
', [$parentId], [
    [
        'a' => 'parent',
        'b' => 'child',
        'matcher' => function($parent, $c) {
            return $parent->id == $c->parent_id;
        },
        'do' => function($p, $c) {
            $p->noLoad()->ownChildList[$c->id] = $c;
        }
    ]
]);

// Ensure we don't get lazily loaded results...
R::nuke();

echo $beans['parent'][$parentId]->ownChildList[$childId]->name, "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Bar
```

We win.

Answer (score 0):

```
$parent = R::dispense('parent');
$parent->name = "darth";

$child = R::dispense('child');
$child->name = "Luke";

$parent->ownChildList[] = $child;
$parent_id = R::store($parent);

// now fetch
$parent = R::load('parent' $parent_id);

echo "$parent has the following kids:";
foreach ($parent->ownChildList as $child){
    echo $child->name . ", ";
}
```